# ARRAY SORTING - I sorted an array (doubles) using the bubble method but there was a string array with corresponded to it - now i cant put it in place

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Im new in java and I am building a system that asks for the name of the course and then the grade the student got - I ask for users input and then display it, so i am using 2 arrays a string array and a doubles array.
At the end I am supposed to print the grades (and the course)  from the highest grade to the lowest. Since I am a begginer we are not allowed to use any other library or import beside the scanner one - I managed to sort the grades using the bubble method but I dont know how to get the corresponding course, since the order has been altered

I have tried putting the student array inside the for or just printing it at the end. The sorting from highest to lowest works fine but I am not sure how to get the number of spots it went up or down to use it in the sting array so it matches the course.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 20; j++) {
            int tmp = 0;
            if (Grade[i] < Grade[j]) //
            {
                tmp = Grade[i];
                Grade[i] = Grade[j];
                Grade[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Grade[i]+"------------"+ Course[i]); /*it just prints the sorted grades but the origial position of the courses*/
    }
    }
```

Comment: The usual technique would be to create a class that represents both a course name and a score, and have an array of that custom object instead of two separate arrays. I'm not sure if that's what your instructor intends, though. If you can post the original assignment text, that might help someone provide help in line with the expectations.

Comment: The alternative is to make the same swaps in the `Course` array that are made in the `Grade` array. FYI: it's conventional in Java to start variable names with a lowercase letter (so `grade` and `course` instead of `Grade` and `Course`). Names starting with an uppercase letter are only used for types (such as `String`, `Array`, and `System`) except for names that are _all_ uppercase, which are used for constants (such as `Math.PI`).

Comment: you can use the same index you use to change the grade to  change the course
`String tmp2 = course[i]; course[i] = course[j]; course[j] = tmp2;`

Comment: There are already several questions on Stack Overflow about sorting parallel arrays in Java. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+sort+parallel+arrays to look at some.